# update-rc.d remove -> insserv: There is a loop between service

Tags: linux, init.d

I have tried to insert of my own procedure to be a part of startup sequence.
This script (**dudriver**) is supposed to be called before mounting disk has been defined in the **/etc/fstab** file.

/etc/init.d/dudriver :

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# kFreeBSD do not accept scripts as interpreters, using #!/bin/sh and sourcing.
if [ true != "$INIT_D_SCRIPT_SOURCED" ] ; then
    set "$0" "$@"; INIT_D_SCRIPT_SOURCED=true . /lib/init/init-d-script
fi

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          dudriver
# Required-Start:    $network $named
# Required-Stop:     umountfs
# Should-Start:      udev
# Should-Stop:       udev
# X-Start-Before:    mountall
# X-Stop-After:      umountfs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: 
# Description:
### END INIT INFO


if [ -x /opt/dudriver_startup.sh ]
then
        /opt/dudriver_startup.sh >>/var/log/dudriver_startup.log
fi

exit 0
```

After some iteration of editing of the **dudriver** script I getting error messages as follows:

```
root@sysman:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d dudriver remove
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and dudriver if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service dudriver at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service umountfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service postgresql at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service cryptdisks at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and dudriver if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service umountnfs at depth 3
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header


root@sysman:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d dudriver defaults
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and dudriver if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service dudriver at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service umountfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service postgresql at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service cryptdisks at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop between service umountfs and dudriver if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service umountnfs at depth 3
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
root@sysman:/etc/init.d#
```

So there is two questions:

1. How to resolve the "loop between" problem ?
2. How to correctly describe LSB header to calling dudriver script before mounting drives ?

PS:uname -a
Linux sysman 4.13.0-31-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 17:11:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: OT here on [so], you should ask on [su] or [sf]. From a quick glance, having the same facility in `Required-Stop` and `X-Stop-After` is a contradiction. Says they should both be stopped after the other.

Comment: Thanks! The question N1 is resolved.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hmmm ... I developed the block device driver and at the time I trying to implement autostart it.  Do I'm need  direct questions to a sysadmin who  not have not a backround in the system programming?

Comment: Is there a way to migrate this topic to corresponding forum ?